# Escribir en archivo .ini sin sección (section)

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando una app que se dirige a una ruta la cual tiene un archivo .ini al cual le agrego unos campos el problema es que me agrega una section y si evito ponerla no me escribe en el archivo.

```
// La clase donde estan las acciones al .ini

class CInifile
    {

// Si elimino el String section no escribe el .ini 

static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);

        public CInifile(string IniPath = null)
        {
            Path = new FileInfo(IniPath ?? EXE + ".ini").FullName;
        }

        public void Write(string Key, string Value, string Section = null)
        {
            WritePrivateProfileString("Nombre de la section", Key, Value, Path);
        }

}
```

Código que llama las funciones de la clase anterior

```
var inifields = new CInifile(CRutas.getFields());
            inifields.Write($"KEY", " VALOR");
```

Y cuando abro el ini queda de la siguiente manera y lo que esta entre [] es lo que no deseo que se agregue:

[Nombre de la section]
KEY = VALOR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo cometes en tu método write:

```
public void Write(string Key, string Value, string Section = null)
{
    WritePrivateProfileString("Nombre de la section", Key, Value, Path);
}
```

Como ves tú mismo estás pasando el nombre de la sección "Nombre de la section"; lo que tienes que poner ahí es el parámetro de la función:

```
public void Write(string Key, string Value, string Section = null)
{
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, Path);
}
```

Ahora cuando llamas a tu función lo puedes hacer bién sin nombre de sección:

```
var inifields = new CInifile(CRutas.getFields());
inifields.Write($"KEY", " VALOR");
```

O asignando un nombre de sección:

```
var inifields = new CInifile(CRutas.getFields());
inifields.Write($"KEY", " VALOR", "Mi Sección");
```

Comment: Lo hice como me dices sin pasar necesariamente el parámetro de la section pero si no lo paso me da error y es el siguiente.

Asistente para la depuración administrada 'PInvokeStackImbalance': 'Una llamada a la función PInvoke 'App!App.Clases.CInifile::WritePrivateProfileString' impidió la correspondencia de la pila. Es posible que la razón sea que la signatura PInvoke administrada no coincida con la signatura de destino no administrada. Compruebe que la convención y los parámetros de llamada de la signatura PInvoke coinciden con la signatura no administrada de destino.'

Comment: Pues, a ver he investigado un poco y se ve que esto da bastantes problemas. Puedes echar un vistazo a [Read ini file which does not have any section?] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686281/read-ini-file-which-does-not-have-any-section) a ver si te pueda sacar de dudas. Vi que cometías el error en la llamada del método y pensé que era un fallo de llamada. Pero ahora creo que _WritePrivateProfileString_ no soporta la escritura sin sección.